# How can I Write Where Query in Fusion Tables

Tags: mysql, google-fusion-tables

I want to select all the coordinates(latlong) where user_id(a Number) = 1 from the fusion table..
I tried using

```
var tableid = "1WjowbI77j1WFcn3IEtbwBymhVZh8jfmP_dg1epd9";
var key = "AIzaSyCALoSz00ZY3zTL1D_xUTD9GMb3T1ocBdU";
var query = "SELECT * FROM "+tableid+"&key="+key+" WHERE user_id=1";
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql="+query
```

didn't work..
Errors :

```
GET googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201W…mP_d‌​g1epd9&key=AIzaSyCALoSz00ZY3zTL1D_xUTD9GMb3T1ocBdU%20WHERE%20user_id=1 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: didn't work is not sufficient, provide your exceptions, errors..??

Comment: GET https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201W…mP_dg1epd9&key=AIzaSyCALoSz00ZY3zTL1D_xUTD9GMb3T1ocBdU%20WHERE%20user_id=1 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is incorrect:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM "+tableid+"&key="+key+" WHERE user_id=1";
```

should be

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM "+tableid+" WHERE user_id=1&key="+key;
```

Comment: Can I compare times in the same way??[link](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT * FROM 1WjowbI77j1WFcn3IEtbwBymhVZh8jfmP_dg1epd9 WHERE Time > '10:25:10 AM'&key=AIzaSyCALoSz00ZY3zTL1D_xUTD9GMb3T1ocBdU)

Comment: That is another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686780/write-query-to-compare-time-in-google-fusion-table  Posted as another question if you are interested in answering..